# SQL query for selecting all items except given name and all rows with id of that given name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologize for the messy title. Please consider following tables:

```
CAR_MODEL : car_model_id, car_name

CAR_INVENTORY : car_model_id, car_location_name,
```

The user would pass in a car_location_name, and I would like to get a list of all car_name **EXCLUDING** rows with given car_location_name, and all cars with the id of that car_location_name.

Let me explain further.

[image: Join]

For a join as such, let's assume that the user passes in "Germany." Then I would like to get a list excluding row #2 and #6, which have car_location_name of "Germany." I would also like to exclude any rows with the car_id of row with Germany. (In this case car_id of 2 and 6, so any row with car_id of 2 or 6 should be eliminated.)
In this case, since Germany has car_id of 2, I would like to get rid of the row with car_location_name of "Canada", since it also has car_id of 2.

The result should be:

[image: Result]

What sql query (Can be sql server specific) can I use to achieve this?

I'm sorry if the explanation is confusing - please ask questions if you are having trouble understanding what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest is probably to do the join to get the results as usual, and then just eliminate all car_model_ids that exist in Germany;

```
SELECT cm.car_model_id, ci.car_location_name, cm.car_name
FROM CAR_MODEL cm
JOIN CAR_INVENTORY ci
  ON cm.car_model_id=ci.car_model_id
WHERE cm.car_model_id NOT IN (
  SELECT car_model_id FROM CAR_INVENTORY WHERE car_location_name='Germany'
)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9cda/3).